# Strong G-Topology on affinoid varieties

Tags: nonarchimedian-analysis, rigid-analytic-spaces

I have a question about the strong G-topology of an affinoid variety. In particular let $X=Sp(A)$ be an affinoid variety and we consider analytic functions $f_1,...,f_m\in A$ on X, having no commom zero on X. I am wondering if the sets

$U_i=\lbrace x\in X \mid f_j(x)<f_i(x) \ \textit{for all} \ j<i \ \textit{and} \  f_j(x)\leq f_i(x) \ \textit{for all} \ \ j\geq i\rbrace$

are admissible open with respect to the strong G-topology. I think one can apply the same arguments as presented in Bosch's book https://link.springer.com/book/9783540125464 in chapter 9.1.4. Proposition 5, but I am not so sure. Maybe this is obvious or totally rubish, but unfortunately I am totally new to the subject and have no intution about auch things.

Moreover if the $U_i$ are admissible, is it than also true, that the covering $\lbrace U_i\rbrace$ is also an admissible covering of $X$? That the sets $U_i$ cover $X$ is obvious, but is it an admissible covering?

Many thanks if someone could help me out.

Comment: $U_i$ is just the intersection of the $\{x,\, f_j(x)<f_i(x)\}$ (for $j < i$) and $\{x,\, f_j(x) \leq f_i(x)\}$ (for $i < j$). All of these are admissible open (iirc), so $U_i$ should be admissible open. I don’t think that the open cover $(U_i)_i$ is admissible, because it looks too much like the standard counter-example $\{|x| < 1\} \cup \{|x|=1\}$. I’m quite rusty though, so don’t take this as gospel.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the sets $U_i$ are definitely admissible and you are potentially also correct with the covering. I ask this question, because in my case $X$ is connected and I can define a function on $X$, which is constant on every $U_i$. I hoped to use a connexity argument to show, that the function is constant. Do you have any idea? Thanks :)

Comment: So your function takes finitely many values. Consider an open cover according to the value it takes?

Comment: True. The problem is, that the function is not an analytic function or anything similar. To be more precise, one can associate to every point in X an integer  and on the sets $U_i$ the integer is always the same. Can I still get an open cover?

Comment: How would you avoid the pitfall of looking too much like $\{|x| < 1\} \cup \{|x|=1\}$ if $f$ is really not analytic?